# How to generate random codes that have to be entered to access a Mailchimp form?

Tags: plugins, code

I want the code to show up somewhere on my landing page. Users will have to enter it into a form before they can enter their actual details. I've heard that interaction and tiny challenges increase the chance of a visitor signing up. Ideally, the generated codes should expire.

Answer (score 0):

Can you precise your question ? Is it something you need to protect your form and avoid robots and spam ? If yes, I think you should use an existant **CAPTCHA** like [Google reCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/) or an alternative such as [VisualCaptcha](https://visualcaptcha.net/) or [Honeypot](https://dev.to/felipperegazio/how-to-create-a-simple-honeypot-to-protect-your-web-forms-from-spammers--25n8) method.